# Issue with allowed ports - docker/django

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, dockerfile, digital-ocean

I have a django project in dockerhub. I pulled and ran the docker image into a digital ocean droplet to test  if working. I am getting the following error:

`Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '167.99.106.66'. You may need to add '167.99.106.66' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.`

now i did add the link into the allowed_hosts in my django setting file, but the url is still now working. is there anyway to fix it or any other info I need to add to get this working:

the following is in the django settings file:

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['167.99.106.66', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']`

Comment: It's not really a good permanent solution, but does it work to set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`?

Comment: so I tried that and I am getting the following line `0eb2949b49c0        error_testing_1     "python manage.py ru…"   Less than a second ago   Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:32768->80/tcp   hopeful_hoover` and i tried running `localhost:32768` and `127.0.0.1:32768` and the page is not working @RishiG

Comment: You should set a FQDN on DNS and use it in the ALLOWED_HOSTS.